# Nfc is opening another application

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I am using nfc for reading card number. All works fine but now I have one problem when nfc detect is working another application is opening above my app.
here is my code

```
class NfcCardDetectService(
    private val context: Activity,
    private val nfcResultListener: NfcResultListener
) :
    NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback {
    private val READTIMEOUT = 3000
    private var mUserAppIndex = -1
    private var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = null
    private lateinit var isoDep: IsoDep
    private var card = Card()
    override fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag?) { }

    fun start() {
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(context)
        if (nfcAdapter != null) {
            if (nfcAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
                nfcResultListener.onNfcStateChanged(false)
            } else {
                nfcResultListener.onNfcStateChanged(true)
                nfcAdapter?.enableReaderMode(context, this, READER_FLAGS, null)
            }
        } else {
            nfcResultListener.onNfcNotSupported()
        }
    }
```

How I can fix this problem ?

Comment: What is the value of `READER_FLAGS`, please show the code setting these.

Comment: @Andrew I am using this flags  
private const val READER_FLAGS = NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A or
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B or
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F or
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V or
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS

Comment: OK setting flags ok so it should route the Tag data to your app BUT I can think of 2 reasons why it might not. 1. `enableReaderMode` is a foreground detection API and has checks to make sure it only delivers it to foreground processes, I cannot tell from the code you have shared if Android would detect it as in the foreground as it looks like a Service class that might be running in the background of your app. 2. There is no details of what the Tag contains as there are a few NDef data type that the OS handles before dispatch, these are thing used for phone settings provisioning.